# group by function in sqlite3 or itertools.groupy in python, sorting and grouping middle values within a string

Tags: python, substring, python-itertools

I have the following connection to a SQLite database returning data in the "phone1" column, I'm looking to skip the area code portion and order by the exchange (middle value) portion of phone1 column. Implementing wildcards seems to work if you're testing for a known exchange, however I'd like group by or order by starting with the 5 string character.

first_name, last_name, company, address, city, county, state, zip, **phone1**, phone2, email, web

```
    (0, ('201-238-5688',))
    (1, ('201-431-2989',))
    (2, ('201-474-4924',))
    (3, ('201-588-7810',))
    (4, ('201-672-1553',))

    .....
    (495, ('973-943-3423',))
    (496, ('978-626-2978',))
    (497, ('978-697-6263',))
    (498, ('979-718-8968',))
    (499, ('985-890-7262',))

import os, csv, json, re
import sqlite3


    conn = sqlite3.connect('US_500.sqlite')
    conn.text_factory = str
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    reader = cursor.execute ("SELECT phone1 FROM SampleData ORDER BY substr(phone1, 5) BETWEEN 200 AND 300")

    tabledata = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in enumerate(tabledata):
        print str(row)

    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I figured it out right after posting, also helpful to know the second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need to group, ordering should be sufficient.

In a SQL query you can use `substr()` to select part of a field, and then order by that. Your query could be:

```
SELECT phone1 FROM SampleData order by substr(phone1, 5, 3)
```

This extracts 3 characters starting at the 5th position (so characters 5, 6 & 7) and uses them for ordering.

Similarly you can also do it in Python by calling `sorted()` on the query results and passing a key function that selects the range of characters by which to sort:

```
tabledata = cursor.fetchall()
for row in enumerate(sorted(tabledata, key=lambda x: x[4:7])):
    print str(row)
```

Comment: I changed the SELECT statement above to select a range between 200 and 300, but doesn't seem to work, ORDER BY seems to return all values and GROUP BY returns only one value outside of the range specified. Any clues?

Comment: @user3724235 : you should probably ask a new question, and read something about SQL. your revised query should be `SELECT phone1 FROM SampleData where substr(phone1, 5, 3) BETWEEN 200 and 300 ORDER BY substr(phone1, 5)`